# localhost not working on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, localhost

I have my Mac's local apache server running <del>and when I visit localhost I get the standard "It Works" page.</del> The "It works" page was cached - it is in fact broken the same as 127.0.0.1. When I visit 127.0.0.1 however chrome gives me `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. So I ran a `telnet`. Result:

```
harryg$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

But `scutil` gives this:

```
harryg$ scutil -r localhost
Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address
```

Any idea why it isn't working? Is apache listening on some different port? If so how do I check? I have some local vhosts which should be accessible by some local `.dev` virtual hosts that I've added to my hosts file. E.g. `127.0.0.1     home.dev` but they too give the error above.

**Edit**

It seems nothing is listening on port 80. When I run `sudo lsof -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN` I get no output. Apache seems to be running though - I have run `apachectl` restart` many times.

Comment: could you check is your webshare is working with this tool;
http://clickontyler.com/web-sharing/

Comment: Your `localhost` is working perfectly fine. Apache isn’t. Update your question to represent this fact and don’t forget to include the relevant bits of your Apache config and its log files.

Comment: I had a similar problem and was able to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454160/get-localhost-running-on-mac-os-x-yosmite

Comment: The normal way to do this on Mavericks/Yosemite is to port forward from port 80 to port 8080. See https://gist.github.com/mindw0rk/dcc6c02a92b49bde0f13 for an example of how to set this up using pfctl, then change your apache config to use Listen 8080. You'll be able to connect to port 80 & traffic will be forwarded to apache. (in our dev shop everyone uses this setup, except with nginx)

Answer (score 11):

Check your Apache config with this command:

```
sudo apachectl -t
```

This tests the config files and tells you if there's an error. Running `sudo apachectl start` does not output config file syntax errors to the logs for some reason.

Comment: Exact same problem here. `sudo apachectl -t` returns `Syntax OK`. What then?

Answer (score 2):

This command should tell you what on which port and which IPv(4/6) address your Apache is listening :

```
sudo lsof -P -n -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep httpd
```

If there is nothing listening, what do you get from this ?

```
sudo serveradmin status web
sudo serveradmin settings web
ps -acx | grep http
```

.

At last resort :

```
sudo serveradmin stop web
```

Open Console.app and place a bookmark

```
sudo serveradmin start web
```

Check the logs

Comment: There was a configuration file issue that prevented Apache from starting at all! Cached pages led me to believe it was running for localhost but not for my local IP.

Comment: Ok cool, serveradmin trigger httpd, and generally generates startup logs, have you been able to resolve the issue ? what is the error message plz (for other members)?

Comment: Yeah it's solved. I had forgotten to uncomment an apache vhosts module so Apache hit an error when it saw `VirtualDocumentRoute` in my vhosts config file.

Comment: hey harryg, if you get the chance update the status to resolved.

Comment: I had this issue and silent failure when starting apache. Nothing in logs, due to a syntax error in the config. This command surfaced it: `sudo apachectl -t`

Comment: Thanks, your `lsof` command helped me with a related issue.

Comment: The `sudo apachectl -t` , using `telnet` really
helped with my problem.    
I installed PHP and MySQL with homebrew     and forgot to uncomment the `LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so` file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default port is 8080, but you can check the httpd.conf file for the ports that Apache is listening on.

Comment: 8080 doesn't work, and my config file has Listen 80 in it.

Comment: Can you see Apache running, perhaps with a "ps aux"? Also, does the error log show anything? Default location should be /var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep :80`?